# Iterate values of HashMap only once

Tags: java, collections, iterator, hashmap

I've a HashMap with several entries. I want to iterate over all the values of HashMap. I want to modify the HashMap while iterating (adding and removing entries). This can be done by using an ListIterator. Right?
But what happens with the new Entries? Will they be iterated too? Or will they be ignored?

Thank you all.

Aeon

Comment: iterator can remove only not add. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html. Please explain your reason for it :)

Comment: What happened when you added mappings to the `HashMap` while an `Iterator` was iterating over it?

Comment: I am sorry, i mean a ListIterator which enables adding and removing.

Comment: @user3637636: There's no such thing for a `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add while using an iterator, it will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

What you can do:

```
Map<String, String> thingsToAdd = new HashMap<>();

for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> i = yourMap.entrySet().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            Map.Entry<String, String> entry = i.next();

    if (...) { // Add things
        thingsToAdd.put(..);
    }

    if (...) { // Remove things
        i.remove();
    }
}

yourMap.addAll(thingsToAdd);
```

Comment: you can remove elements using the itaretor.remove() method